# Who is responsible for deallocating memory reserved in the .bss section of an image?

Tags: linux, memory-management, assembly, x86

If I reserve memory in the .BSS section of an image, am I responsable for deallocating that memory before the process terminates and if so how do I go about doing this?

Here's some example code to clarify

```
SECTIION .text
GLOBAL _start
_start:
mov edx, buffer
movb [edx], 30h ; Initializes buffer which was reserved in .bss
...

SECTION .bss
buffer: RESB 2 ; Reserves 2 bytes in .bss section
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The loader allocates that memory before your process starts executing, and the kernel will automatically reclaim it when your process exits.  You do not need to worry about it.